# angular-cli build works, build --prod fails

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am working on an Angular 4 project that utilizes angular-cli.  It is finally *almost* done -- and yet *another* stumbling block.

If I run `ng build` the project builds fine.

If I run `ng build --prod` the following error is thrown:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling
>   function 'makeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider
>   replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported
>   function, resolving symbol Injectable in
>   C:/SRC/Sandbox/eat-sleep-code.com/node_modules/ng2-gist/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/metadata.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol OpaqueToken in
>   C:/SRC/Sandbox/eat-sleep-code.com/node_modules/ng2-gist/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/opaque_token.d.ts, resolving symbol OpaqueToken in
>   C:/SRC/Sandbox/eat-sleep-code.com/node_modules/ng2-gist/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/opaque_token.d.ts
>
> ERROR in ./src/main.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in
>   'C:\SRC\Sandbox\eat-sleep-code.com\src'  @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74  @
>   multi ./src/main.ts

How do I get around this?

Comment: From the error it seems like you wrote some `makeDecorator` function that is throwing errors

Comment: I didn't.   Perhaps a plugin is.   I see it is mentioning the ng2-gist plugin.   However, why does it build correctly without the prod flag?

Comment: Prod flag  I am assuming has some stricter criteria like check that nothing is being unused or not being drawn from a local library that's my guess

Comment: makeDecorator appears to be an Angular function.   ng2-gist has angular2 libraries under it.

Comment: angular library should not contain `node_modules` folder with angular modules. Just copy `ng2Gist` component in your project https://github.com/jasonhodges/ng2-gist/blob/master/src/ng2-gist.component.ts

Comment: @yurzui Hmm, what did I miss?  I did an npm uninstall of the ng2-gist plugin and copied the ng2-gist component over.   But now I get this error on build:  `ERROR in ./src/app/ng2-gist.component.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at Promise.resolve.then.then.then (C:\SRC\Sandbox\eat-sleep-code.com\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:350:40)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 20:0-47
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts`

Comment: Strange. I've just tried it and it works with aot. There is very simple code

Comment: You're getting error that is related with `_getResourcesUrls` function inside `@ngtool/webpack` Looks like you have wrong path somewhere

Comment: The developer of ng2Gist module had an empty styles[] definition in their component.   An update to webpack2 back in March introduced behavior that raises an error if there are empty styles[]

Comment: @yurzui If you want to recap it in an "answer", I will give you your credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular library should not contain `node_modules`. It will raise unpredictable errors.

I would advice you to create your own copy `ng2Gist` directive in your project because it is very simple directive